# Is it possible to make Convert.ChangeType() accept currency?

Tags: c#, .net

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.CurrencySymbol = "$";

var result1 = decimal.Parse("$123456", NumberStyles.Any, nfi).Dump(); // this works well
var result2 = Convert.ChangeType("$123456", typeof(decimal), nfi); // this doesn't work
```

I need Convert.ChangeType() to accept currency, is it possible? Tried setting NumberFormatInfo but looks like it ignores currency values.

Comment: No.  The second option is not removing the dollar sigh while first ignores the dollar sign.

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType` internally calls `Convert.ToDecimal`, which defaults to `NumberStyles.Number`: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1688  I doubt there's a way around that

Comment: Alas, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToDecimal_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) states that `The base types ignore provider`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are tied down to `Convert.ChangeType`?

Comment: @Fildor I'm making a custom value converter for our solution and want write as less code as possible. Convert.ChangeType works well for many others. Looks like I have to implement all those XXX.Parse for numeric types.

Comment: @LINQ2Vodka An interesting question. You could potentially look at implementing your own converter that wraps reflected calls to `TryParse`. This will work with all value types

Comment: You  could get `Parse` method with reflection from necessary type and invoke with appropriate  parameters and use like `ToNumber<decimal>(inputValie, NumberStyles.Any,nfi)`

Answer (score 1):

`Convert` is a static class and also `ChangeType()` is a static method, so you can not override them.

Even if this is not exactly what you have asked for, however, you may create your own class change the way you want it to work for decimal (and any others) and use `Convert.ChangeType()` as default for other types:

```
public static class MyConvert 
{
     public static object? ChangeType(object? value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
     {
         if (conversionType == typeof(decimal))
             return decimal.Parse(value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, provider);
         else
             return Convert.ChangeType(value, conversionType, provider);
     }
}
```

Now the following code would work as you expect:

```
var result2 = MyConvert.ChangeType("$123456", typeof(decimal), nfi);
```